# Pandas groupby year filtering the dataframe by n largest values

Tags: pandas, filtering, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe at hourly level with several columns. I want to extract the entire rows (containing all columns) of the 10 top values of a specific column for every year in my dataframe.

so far I ran the following code:

```
df = df.groupby([df.index.year])['totaldemand'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(10)))
```

The problem here is that I only get the top 10 values for each year of that specific column and I lose the other columns. How can I do this operation and having the corresponding values of the other columns that correspond to the top 10 values per year of my 'totaldemand' column?

Comment: Can you post sample dataset with expected outputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*nlargest* can be applied to each group, passing the column to look for
largest values.

So run:

```
df.groupby([df.index.year]).apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(3, 'totaldemand'))
```

Of course, in the final version replace *3* with your actual value.

Answer (score 1):

We usually do `head` after `sort_values`

```
df = df.sort_values('totaldemand',ascending = False).groupby([df.index.year])['totaldemand'].head(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of your query and use it as a mask on your original `df`:

```
idx = df.groupby([df.index.year])['totaldemand'].apply(lambda grp: grp.nlargest(10))).index.to_list()
df.iloc[idx,]
```

(or something to that extend, I can't test now without any test data)